# Generic Question: Thoughts on soft keyboard UI for mobile devices

Tags: user-interface, mobile, keyboard

Yo, so I was curious about your thoughts about your preferences on soft keyboards for mobile devices.  Are there any particularly innovative ones that you like?

By the way, my ulterior motive for asking this question was to look up one particular instance that I heard about, oh 10-ish months ago. Basically, you type with your finger constantly on the keyboard. Based on your direction changes and speed, the keyboard is supposed to be a much better predictor of keys.  I'd really appreciate it if you

Pardon me for using this as a search for information, but it apparently made a much smaller smash in the gadget news sources, and implementations haven't come out yet.

Comment: Found it: I think I was talking about this one: [http://www.cootek.com/](http://www.cootek.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that it is much easier to type on keyboards that display the letter you are pressing as you press it. Also that the said letter is not put in until you lift your finger off of it. Like seen on the iPod and iPhone, and my current phone the LG Dare.

This is really good if you are working with a small space for the keyboard. If you are developing a keyboard I suggest using this method.